# Weird behaviour on File.Exists() on C# .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, system.io.file

I am currently working on a program on WinForms on Visual Studio Community 2022. The program has to check if a file exists on the install directory using File.Exists(), but there is a really weird behaviour that I cannot seem to solve: when debugging (and even running it in the Release mode) the application on VS2022, the value the method returns is false (which is right, because the file doesn't exist at the moment of running the method), but when installing the application, it says the file exists, even when it doesn't, and it can even read the content of that file. Here's the code:

```
private static string AppPath = $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)}\eMA\eMA";

public async Task<JArray> GetVersionsJArrayFromComputer()
        {
            JArray versionsJArray = new JArray();
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string path = AppPath;
                if (!await CheckIfVersionJSONFileExists())
                {
                    if (!await IsRunningAsAdmin())
                    {
                        await RunAsAdmin();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await SaveVersionJSONFile(await SetVersionsJArrayFromComputer());
                    }
                }
                string versionFilePath = $@"{path}\version.json";
                string versionFile = File.ReadAllText(versionFilePath);
                versionsJArray = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(versionFile);
            });
            return versionsJArray;
        }

private static async Task<bool> CheckIfVersionJSONFileExists()
        {
            bool fileExists = false;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string path = AppPath;
                string fileName = $@"{path}\version.json";
                fileExists = File.Exists(fileName);
            });
            return fileExists;
        }
```

I created some MessageBoxes to try to debug the application when it is already installed, and this is what it says:
[image]

This is the content that it reads from the file (and, in theory, if the file doesn't exist, it shouldn't have any content):
[image]

And I don't really know why would it say the file doesn't exist when debugging and then it exists when installed. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use a tool like Process Monitor to dig further please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon Windows UAC can move files to virtualized locations, so `File.Exists` can indeed behave different from your intuition.

Comment: Are you running the program as the same user who is running Visual Studio? I ask because this could very well be a permissions issue.

Comment: Maybe you are experiencing [UAC Virtualization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681)?

Comment: A .NET 5+ project generates .json files by itself, they get deployed along with the executable files.  So if you've tried running the release build of your app to check if it is okay, you now got one more .json file that gets deployed as well :)  That makes keeping this file in the same directory as your app less than ideal.  Beyond needing elevation to write it, the appdata directory should normally be the preferred choice.

Comment: when running locally - attach the debugger and step through the code as you step over the `File.Exists` check confirm yourself that the file does not exist. This will confirm which setup is behaving 'weird'. If the file does actuallly exist, then it seems like that as another poster said, it could be permissions. If it actually doesn't exist then the issue is likely with the 'installed version' - can you install it locally? if so you can attach vs to the running process and debug it that way and once again do the same thing.

Also why are you running everything in Tasks?

Comment: [UAC virtualization issues](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681). Your problem is UAC virtualization.

Comment: Hi joseenrique61, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)